# Java regexp to Lucene converter?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, kibana

I have near to 40 regexps written and working fine in Java (By java i mean it works with the regex matcher in java). I want to run these same regex on kibana connected to an es for the same kind of strings. I can sit and convert each one of them into Lucene and make it work. Is there an easier way of doing this? I dont really want to maintain two sets of regexps. Did some search through the internet but couldnt find anything